# ProgressBar not visually showing all steps

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I made an application that creates 3D models inside Autodesk Inventor. I would like to add a progress bar to show the user how much of the process has finished.

The problem I encounter is that when the process in Autodesk Inventor is consuming a lot of CPU, the progress bar isn't showing all steps and instead jumps (for example 5 steps further) to the end.

Is there a way to force the windows form to show the all the steps? Or is this behavior not common?

```
Private Sub
    ' Display the ProgressBar control.
    pbBuildProgress.Visible = True
    ' Set Minimum to 1 to represent the first file being copied.
    pbBuildProgress.Minimum = 1
    ' Set Maximum to the total number of files to copy.
    pbBuildProgress.Maximum = BodyComponents.Count
    ' Set the initial value of the ProgressBar.
    pbBuildProgress.Value = 1
    ' Set the Step property to a value of 1 to represent each file being copied.
    pbBuildProgress.Step = 1


    ' Start loop trough all body components
    For i = 0 To BodyComponents.Count - 1

        ' Some code here that does stuff in Autodesk Inventor

        ' Perform a step
        pbBuildProgress.PerformStep()

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using a [BackgroundWoker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) to report progress:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = 10

    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    For i = 0 To 10

        Debug.Write(i)

        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged

    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

End Sub
```

It's not something I ever need to do so if someone with more experience has any input I'll be more than happy to learn a thing or two.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your progressbar or form after .PerformStep(). But be aware, it takes a lot of time, especially when your maximum is big. Maybe you could work with a StopWatch and update your form every 250 ms for example.

Comment: Could you please explain a little but further? what takes alot of time? the updating of the form? How should adding multiple (and maybe unnecessary) updates help then?

Comment: It takes a lot of time to paint/update your form. You should prevent the form from unnecessary updates, not force it ;-) Try for example the use of a StopWatch and do only your updates every 250ms (maybe with Application.DoEvents). This will prevent your application from freezing.

Comment: A `Stopwatch` is for measuring the time something takes, not running code every _x_ milliseconds. And you _**SHOULD NOT**_ use `Application.DoEvents()`! Doing so is almost always bad practice. See: [**Keeping your UI Responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/).

Answer (score 0):

**A common cause is that the UI thread is called way too often than it can handle.**

Simple fix for this is to *quantize* you percentage progress, below I run an operation that iterates 1 billion times but only sends an UI update every 10 million iterations or 1%.

Code:

```
var steps = 1000000000;
var step = 1.0d / steps;
var percent = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++)
{
    var percent1 = (int) (Math.Floor(i * step * 100));
    if (percent1 > percent)
    {
        // TODO invoke your UI progress bar update here
        Console.WriteLine("Updating: percent = {0}, i = {1}", percent1, i);
        percent = percent1;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Updating: percent = 1, i = 10000000
Updating: percent = 2, i = 20000000
Updating: percent = 3, i = 30000000
Updating: percent = 4, i = 40000000
Updating: percent = 5, i = 50000000
Updating: percent = 6, i = 60000000
Updating: percent = 7, i = 70000000
Updating: percent = 8, i = 80000000
Updating: percent = 9, i = 90000000
Updating: percent = 10, i = 100000000
Updating: percent = 11, i = 110000000
Updating: percent = 12, i = 120000000
Updating: percent = 13, i = 130000000
Updating: percent = 14, i = 140000000
Updating: percent = 15, i = 150000000
Updating: percent = 16, i = 160000000
Updating: percent = 17, i = 170000000
Updating: percent = 18, i = 180000000
Updating: percent = 19, i = 190000000
Updating: percent = 20, i = 200000000
```

**You might also want to run such operation asynchronously:**

[Task-based Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx)